# how can I edit PHP INI file if I am using UWAMP

Tags: php, uwamp

I found that PHP INI is located in C:\UwAmp\bin\apache\php.ini

If I edit this file, and restart apache server, the file is restored automatically to the last version

any ideas? I am using UWAMP

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The php in the apache directory is dynamically created at every run of uwamp

You need to edit the bin/php/php_[version]/php_uwamp.ini

You can do this manually with the textedit or just run the uwamp gui and select the icon next to the phpconfig button .

This should open your notepad with the correct php_uwamp.ini file

Then when it detects changes apache restarts and creates a php.ini from the above file

Answer (score 0):

You need to open notepad as "Run as administrator" then locate the below path and open php.ini, edit and save, restart apache server.